# How to do I compose a part of dynamic lambda expression which contains operations inside it in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, operators, expression

So I have a scenario where I need to reach the following final lambda expression:

```
v => Convert.ToInt32(v.COLUMN_NAME.Substring(start_index, length)) < Convert.ToInt32(v.ANOTHER_COLUMN_NAME.Substring(start_index, length))
```

v is also dynamic(received from another lambda by taking its parameter), COLUMN_NAME and ANOTHER_COLUMN name both are dynamic(retrieved from a separated DB) and Substring, < operators are also retrieved from DB.
start_index is a calculated value, where start_index = v.COLUMN_NAME.Length()
How to create this expression whose sub-expressions are also dynamic basically.

For non-complex expression(i.e i am able to take COLUMN_NAME and VALUE to be compared as the VALUE is given to me directly as a DB entry, this is the code I use:

```
ParameterExpression p = primaryQuery.Parameters[0]


var pr = Expression.PropertyOrField(p, filter.COLUMN_NAME);
var val = Expression.Constant(filter.COLUMN_VALUE);
MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
// this scenario is particular for operator fetched from filter table = Equals
containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(val, method, pr);
Expression.Lambda<Func<TABLE_TO_BE_QUERIED, bool>>(containsMethodExp, p);
```

I have been stuck here for quite long now, any insights?

Answer (score 1):

I would propose more usable solution using LINQKit:

```cs
public static class MyDbFunctions
{
    [Expandable(nameof(LessThanImpl))]
    public static bool LessThan(string str1, string str2, int start_index, int lenght)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(str1.Substring(start_index, length)) < Convert.ToInt32(str2.Substring(start_index, length));
    }

    private static Expression<Func<string, string, int, int, bool>> LessThanImpl()
    {
        return (str1, str2, start_index, lenght) =>
            Convert.ToInt32(str1.Substring(start_index, length)) < Convert.ToInt32(str2.Substring(start_index, length))
    }
}
```

And usage is simple:

```cs
query = query
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(v => MyDbFunctions.LessThan(v.COLUMN_NAME, v.ANOTHER_COLUMN_NAME, start_index, length));
```